# how custom margin react-loading in react js

Tags: reactjs, loading

i want custom style like margin-left, height, widht in react-loading. 
i'm only can custom color, but custom margin doesn't work.

```
<Loading type ='spinningBubbles' color='#0088CF' />
```

Best wishes! Wish for replying.

Comment: Use `css` or `style` attribute.

Comment: can you explain detail for that ?. thaks @sulthan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add custom styles using the [`style` prop](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#style) on DOM element components.

```
<div style={{ margin: '100px' }}>
    <Loading type ='spinningBubbles' color='#0088CF' />
</div>
```

if you have access to change the `loading` component you could pass the style (or just the margin value) through to the underlying DOM elements as a prop.

If you have a lot of custom styling to do, there is a great library called [Radium](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium) for making it easier.